# I want to print all the element added in list but it is only printing the last element.(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
n = int(input())

for x in range(0,n):
    a = []
    y = int(input())
    a.insert(x,y)
print(a)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you create a new list every iteration? Also try to use `.append(x)` instead of `.insert(x, y)` as they are equivalent in this context

Comment: I know but I want to add custom value. BTW thanks. I got the solution now.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize `a` once for all **before** the loop:

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for x in range(0,n):
    y = int(input())
    a.insert(x,y)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Having `a` initialization inside the loop overwrites the value of the array in  *each*  iteration, starting it outside of the loop will get you the expected result

Comment: but I am giving the list an index where the value should be stored. Then how it overwrites the same index.

Comment: You are still initializing `a` each time the loop executes

Let's say your first number is 3, then, by the end of the first run you'll have `a = [3]`.
But in the next run, you are assigning `a` to be an empty array again, then you lost number `3`.